# SQL server join on the same table twice to update a record of a column on the basis of a record in another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have the following table (table ConfigValue) in which features and options are declared (a zero for visible means that the option of the feature is not visible and one means the option is visible. For value, a zero means that an option is not selected and a one means that an option is selected):

```
Feature_ID | OptionValue | value | visible
---------- | ----------- | ----- | -------
300        | 1           | 0     | 1
310        | 2           | 0     | 1
```

I want to use the following table (table OptionValue) to create a dependency between options. In this case Option 2 from feature 310 should not be visible (i.e. visible = 0), when option 1 from feature 300 is selected (i.e. value = 1). On the other hand, option 2 from feature 310 should be visible when option 1 from feature 300 is not selected.

```
Feature_ID_1 | OptionValue_1 | Feature_ID_2 | OptionValue_2 | 
------------ | ------------- | ------------ | ---------
300          | 1             | 310          | 2
```

I want to translate the above into an update statement, but I have no idea where to begin.

---

Update based on Squirrel's answer

The following select statement yields the correct output

```
Select CF.FeatureID    As Feature_ID_1, 
   CF.OptionValue  As OptionValue_1,
   CF.value AS Value_1,
   CF.visible AS Visible_1,
   OV.FeatureID    As Feature_ID_2, 
   OV.OptionValue    As OptionValue_2, 
   OV.value AS Value_2,
   Case When CF.Value = 1 Then 0 Else 1 End As Visible_2
   From   [VlastuinTEST].[dbo].[ConfigValue] as CF
   Cross Join [VlastuinTEST].[dbo].[ConfigValue] as OV
   Where  CF.FeatureID = 300
   And    OV.FeatureID = 310
```

It returns visible is 0 for option 2 from feature 310, when option 1 from feature 300 is selected. However, I do need the second table, as I want to fill this table with the combinations of options that should not be visible when other options are selected (so in OptionValue feature_ID_1 and OptionValue_1 should represent Feature_ID and OptionValue in ConfigValue where value is 1, while Feature_ID_2 and OptionValue_2 should represent Feature_ID and OptionValue in ConfigValue where visible should be updated to 0).

How can I still make use of the OptionValue table in this case? Also, what needs to be changed to make an update query of the select query?

Comment: Begin by first writing a `SELECT` query that would show you the record that you need to update as well as the value you need to set. You can start by looking at some simple tutorials on how to write `INNER JOIN`s e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp and searching the Internet

Comment: don't quite understand your description on the issue. This statement `Option 1 from feature 310 should not be visible (i.e. visible = 0)` does not seems like coincide with the sample data that you posted. Also how did `OptionValue_1` become `2` and `OptionValue_2` become `1` ?

Comment: @Squirrel sorry my bad. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you wanted ?

```
Select CF.FeatureID    As Feature_ID_1, 
       CF.OptionValue  As OptionValue_1,
       OV.FeatureID    As Feature_ID_2, 
       Case When CF.OptionValue = 1 Then 0 Else 1 End As OptionValue_2
From   [VlastuinTEST].[dbo].[ConfigValue] as CF
Cross Join [VlastuinTEST].[dbo].[ConfigValue] as OV
Where  CF.FeatureID = 300
And    OV.FeatureID = 310
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer squirrel. I edited the query a bit to get the correct output. However, I still have a question (this question can be found in my main question, on top)